# d3.js throws an error 't.slice is not a function'

Tags: jquery, d3.js, momentjs

I've created some line charts on a web page. The code below is quite long but actually simple. It fetches some data from database via ajax, then format and filter the data (so there are two arrays of objects nodata i rawdata) and pass the data to d3.js line chart. I embed the line chart in function draw(). This function starts on click with appropriate data. I work perfect when I start first line chart but when I try to star another it throws me an error 't.slice is not a function'. The work fine separate but not together. Am I missing something... How to reiniciate the line chart?

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {


function wykresy(iii) { 
  
  var fff;
  //Zmienna wysyła id postu do ajaxa
  var ids = iii;
  var data = {
        'action': 'press_release',
        'ids' : ids,
        'security': frontendajax.nncs 
        };

 
     $.post(frontendajax.ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
      var fff = response;
      //String z bazą danych pochodzącą z inputu baza w adminie via custom post type 'baza'
      return fff;
     }).then(function(fff){
      
    //Formatowanie stringa z bazą danych      
    var ttt = fff.split("; ");
    var i;
    //Array of objects z bazą danych
    var rawdata = [];
    for (i = 1 ; i < ttt.length ; i++ ) {
     //Tworzenie objektów JSON z rekordami bazy danych  
     var obj = jQuery.parseJSON( ttt[i] );
     //console.log(typeof obj);
     rawdata.push(obj);
     
    
    }
    //console.log(data);
    
    // Get the data
    //Formatowanie daty
    
    
    
    //Filtrowanie danych
    var fel = $('#dodaty').val();
    var tttt = moment(fel, "DD-MM-YYYY").toDate();
    var smak = moment(rawdata[rawdata.length-1].label, "YYYY-MM-DD").subtract(8, 'month').toDate();
    var nodata = [];
    var w;
    for(w = 0 ; w < rawdata.length ; w++) {
     
     
     
     var y = rawdata[w];
     if(moment(y.label, "YYYY-MM-DD").toDate() < smak) {
      nodata.push(y);
      }
    
    }
    
    //console.log(data);
    
    console.log(nodata[0].label);
    console.log(rawdata[0].label);
    console.log(nodata[0].value1);
    console.log(rawdata[0].value1);
    console.log(typeof nodata[0].label);
    console.log(typeof rawdata[0].label);
    console.log(typeof nodata[0].value1);
    console.log(typeof rawdata[0].value1);


    
    
    
    
    
    
    function draw(data, iii) {
    //Formatowanie wszystkich rekordów w bazie
    var parselabel = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d").parse;
    data.forEach(function(d){
     
     return d.label = parselabel(d.label);
     
    });
    //Wartość pierwszego rekordu bazy
    var first = data[0].value1;
    //Wartość ostatniego rekordu bazy
    var last = data[data.length - 1].value1;
    //Obliczanie wartości procentowej wzrostu dla ostaniego rekordu w bazie
    var lastPercent = Math.round(((data[data.length - 1].value1 - data[0].value1) / data[0].value1)*100);
    //Wartość ostatniego rekordu w bazie - data
    var lastDay = data[data.length - 1].label;
    //Wartość pierwszego rekordu w bazie - data
    var firstDay = data[0].label;
    //InfoBox nad tabelą ():
    $('.info-'+ iii + ' > .tthree > p > span').text(" " + lastDay.toLocaleDateString());
    $('.info-'+ iii + ' > .tone > h5').html(last + "<span> PLN</span>");
    //Inputy nad tabelą - zakres dat 
    $('.wykres-'+ iii + ' > .inputy > #oddaty').val(firstDay.toLocaleDateString());
    $('.wykres-'+ iii + ' > .inputy > #dodaty').val(lastDay.toLocaleDateString());
    //Marginesy dla obrazka SVG 
    //Na podstawie szerokości aktualnego okna przeglądarki
    var szerokosci = $('.wykres').width();
    //alert(szerokosci);
    
    
    var margin = {top: 60, right: 40, bottom: 60, left: 60},
        width = szerokosci - margin.left - margin.right,
        height = 453 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
        
    //Oblicza wartość x dla y przy funkcji mouseover
    var bisectDate = d3.bisector(function(d) { return d.label; }).left;
    //Format daty
    var formatDate = d3.time.format("%d-%b");
    
    //Formatowanie parametrów linii osi x i y 
    var x = d3.time.scale().range([0, width]);
    var y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);
    
    //Rysuje oś x wykresu oraz przedziały na niej
    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x)
        .orient("bottom").ticks(4).tickFormat(d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d"));
    //Rysuje oś y wykresu oraz przedziały na niej
    var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y)
        .orient("left").ticks(4).tickFormat(function(d) { return Math.round(((d - data[0].value1) / data[0].value1)*100) + "%"; });
    
    //Deklaracja wykresu na osi y,x 
    var valueline = d3.svg.line()
        .x(function(d) { return x(d.label); })
        .y(function(d) { return y(d.value1); });
        
    //Rysuje główne okno svg z grupą elementów g
    var troll = d3.select("#tests-"+ iii).append("svg")
            .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
            .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom);
    
    var svg = troll
        .append("g")
            .attr("transform", 
                  "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    // Dodajemy domenę wartości osi x i y - zmienia skalę osi x i y z parametrów width i height na skalę określoną przez zakres danych 
    x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.label; }));
    y.domain([data[0].value1, d3.max(data, function(d) {
     return Math.max(d.value1); })]);
    
    
    
    //  
    function make_x_axis() {        
        return d3.svg.axis()
            .scale(x)
             .orient("bottom")
             .ticks(4);
    }
      
    function make_y_axis() {        
        return d3.svg.axis()
            .scale(y)
            .orient("left")
            .ticks(4);
    }
    
    // Dodajemy linię wykresu danych do obrazka svg
    svg.append("path")        
       .attr("d", valueline(data))
       .attr("class", "wykresik");
       
    // Dodajemy zdefiniowaną oś x wykresu
    svg.append("g")            
        .attr("class", "x axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
        .call(xAxis);
        
    //Dodajemy zdefiniowaną oś y wykresu
    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "y axis")
        .call(yAxis); 
    //Rysuje element grupowy, który pomieści animacje funkcji mouseover
    var focus = svg.append("g")                                
        .style("display", "none");  
            
    //Dodajemy siatk wykresu - w tym wypadku tylko horyzontalną siatkę
    svg.append("g")         
        .attr("class", "grid")
        .call(make_y_axis()
            .tickSize(-width, 0, 0)
            .tickFormat("")
      );
              
     // Rysujemy linię x animacji mouseover
    focus.append("line")
        .attr("class", "x param")
        .attr("y1", 0)
        .attr("y2", height);
    
    // Rysujemy linię y animacji mouseover
    focus.append("line")
        .attr("class", "y param")
        .attr("x1", width)
        .attr("x2", width);
    
    // Dodajemy kółeczko animacji mouseover
    focus.append("circle")
        .attr("class", "y circle")
        .attr("r", 6);
    
    // Dodajemy tekst do kółeczka a aktualną wartością 
    focus.append("text")
        .attr("class", "y1 text")
        .style("opacity", 0.8)
        .attr("dx", 12)
        .attr("dy", "-.6em");
            
    focus.append("text")
        .attr("class", "y2 text")
        .attr("dx", 12)
        .attr("dy", "-.6em");
        
        
    
    // Dodajemy tekst do kółeczka a aktualną datą
    focus.append("text")
        .attr("class", "y3 text")
        .style("opacity", 0.8)
        .attr("dx", 12)
        .attr("dy", "1em");
    focus.append("text")
        .attr("class", "y4 text")
        .attr("dx", 12)
        .attr("dy", "1em");                                 
        
    // Dodajemy kwadrat który będzie służył jako canvas dla pozycji myszy              
    svg.append("rect")                                    
        .attr("width", width)                              
        .attr("height", height)                            
        .style("fill", "none")                             
        .style("pointer-events", "all")                    
        .on("mouseover", function() { focus.style("display", null); })
        .on("mouseout", function() { focus.style("display", "none"); })
        .on("mousemove", mousemove); 
          
    var legenda = svg.append("g");
    legenda.append("text")
           .attr("class", "wyniktext")
           .attr("x", 0)
           .attr("y", -20)
           .text("Wynik: ");
    legenda.append("text")
           .attr("class", "mytext")
           .attr("x", 80)
           .attr("y", -20)
           .text(lastPercent + "%");
    
                           
    
    //Funkcja definiuje animacje zależne od pozycji myszy na wykresie
    function mousemove() {  
         ////console.log(bisectDate);                               
            var x0 = x.invert(d3.mouse(this)[0]),              
                i = bisectDate(data, x0, 1),                             
                d0 = data[i - 1],                              
                d1 = data[i],                                  
                d = x0 - d0.label > d1.label - x0 ? d1 : d0;   
                //console.log(d.label);
                //console.log(d.value1); 
    
         focus.select("circle.y")                           
                .attr("transform", "translate(" + x(d.label) + "," + y(d.value1) + ")");  
                                           
         focus.select("circle.y")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + x(d.label) + "," + y(d.value1) + ")");
    
        focus.select("text.y1")
            .attr("transform","translate(" + x(d.label) + "," + y(d.value1) + ")")
            .text(d.value1);
    
        focus.select("text.y2")
         .attr("transform","translate(" + x(d.label) + "," + y(d.value1) + ")")
            .text(d.value1);
    
        focus.select("text.y3")
            .attr("transform","translate(" + x(d.label) + "," + y(d.value1) + ")")
            .text(formatDate(d.label));
    
        focus.select("text.y4")
            .attr("transform","translate(" + x(d.label) + "," +y(d.value1) + ")")
            .text(formatDate(d.label));
            
      legenda.select("text.mytext").text(Math.round(((d.value1 - data[0].value1) / data[0].value1)*100) + "%");
        
        focus.select(".x")
            .attr("transform","translate(" + x(d.label) + "," + 0 + ")")
                .attr("y2", height);
    
        focus.select(".y")
            .attr("transform","translate(" + width * -1 + "," + y(d.value1) + ")")
                .attr("x2", width + width);
       
        }      
     }
     
     
    $('#test').click(function(){
     draw(nodata, 30); 
    });
    $('#test3m').click(function(){
     draw(rawdata, 30); 
    });  
     
     
     
                             
     });

}
  
  wykresy(30); 
 
     
});
```

Comment: The `t.slice is not a function` error is a clue that you are asking `d3` to do an array-like operation (`slice`) on something that is not an array (whatever d3 is calling `t`). What does `console.log(data)` give you in the `draw` function?

Comment: the problem laid on parseLabel function - I used moment() instead and somehow it works fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you're trying to re-parse data that has already been parsed initially (`label` is already `Date` when clicking on a chart for the second time).